# Solve for initial velocity based on 2 points, with a negative distance

Tags: calculus, integration

## Solve for initial Velocity based on $-d$ and $+d$ and their times.

Ok lets just imagine that we have a rubber band sling shot, and the distance $d = 0$ is in the middle of that slingshot.

I am trying to get a distance equation so that I can programmatically calculate distance at time $t$.

Kind of like this slingshot how it is tight in the middle
[Slingshot With Tight Band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JpKT.png)

So from what I am aware, the elastic potential energy is like

$e = Kd^2$

Where $K$ is the elasticitiy strength, and $d$ is the distance.

---

So I believe my acceleration at any point in time is really just
(I am purely only interested in the vertical acceleration):

$A = -1 * sgn(d) * Kd^2$

However based on this I have no idea how I can create a distance function, or even if it is possible.

---

Because my final step is that I really just want to be able to determine the **Initial Velocity** given 2 points(1 potentially $-d$ and 1 $+d$) and their times at each location.

I would love some pointers on how to solve that above problem, or even if I am going about it the right way.

Thanks! :)

---

**EDIT**

How can I even calculate the integral of that acceleration function, if someone could please show that that would be awesome.

Comment: What is the weighf of the load?

Comment: Oh I Im not sure. I should probably include that in the calculation as well right? 

Comment: @WilliamElliot what if we just assume the weight is 1 and in kg

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the slingshot is oriented at some angle $\theta$, is it oriented purely vertically, etc? Is the ball secured to the slingshot or does it get slung off?

Comment: @skip that is correct. purely vertical and its attached to the rubber band